# CSS3 Rotation Snapback

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a little fun toy to play with on my website, basically whenever you hover the logo, it rotates until you remove the cursor. I have achieved this by using rotate in CSS3, and it is working. But i was wondering if there is a way to prevent the "Snapback" (Smoothly bring it back to its original position when you unhover instead of it just jumping back instantly)

The code i am using is this:

```
    #logo1:hover{
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.7s infinite linear;
-moz-animation: spin 0.7s infinite linear;
-o-animation: spin 0.7s infinite linear;
-ms-animation: spin 0.7s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

im thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying can be easily accomplished by simply using CSS3 transforms, animation is not required here as you are starting from 0 to 360 deg so try this

```
.class {
   -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
   /* Add up other required proprietary properties here */
   transition: all 1s; /* This will handle the transition to be 
                          smooth on mouse out */
}

.class:hover {
   -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
   /* Add up other required proprietary properties here and 
      transition property is not required here */
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. However, that only spins once. Is there a way to have it spinning for as long as you keep the cursor on the div, and then ease back to the original position whenever you unhover it?

Comment: @SimonAndersson No, than you need to increase the deg, like 360, 720, etc, if you want the animation to go on, better use CSS3 animations, also you can increase the rotation degree by 10 times and see